# What is Haskell's grammar and which type of parser can parse it?

Tags: java, parsing, haskell, cross-compiling, grammar

I'm trying to make a parsing library for JDK 11.x that reads Haskell code as input, then translates it into Java to be executed by the JVM. I'm calling it Jaskell, but I need to know Haskell's formal grammar structure in order to determine what type of parser Jaskell needs to be (i.e. LL or LR parser).

Comment: If you have to ask this question, then you have no hope of completing that highly ambitious project. Also, note that [Frege](https://github.com/Frege/frege) and [Eta](https://eta-lang.org/) both already do that.

Comment: I'm asking because I am unfamiliar with Haskell and new to writing interpreters/parsers

Comment: Trying to write a compiler or interpreter for a large, complex language that you're unfamiliar with is a bad idea, especially if you don't understand interpreters or parsers. You should pick a much simpler project to get your feet wet with.

Comment: Also, those are essentially cross-compilers. I want this library to be a parser written in Java that reads Haskell, parses it, and compiles it into Java.

Comment: @NoahStutznegger I tried to argue that cross compiling is even harder than compiling because the conceptual differences to bridge are bigger (as I tried to point out in the answer aside dumping info about the grammar).  Except you make everything type `Object` or so, which seems to work somehow since there's the cross-compiler chain haskell->javascript-> java. If you get it running you could get a preview of the resulting java. Scala is closer to Haskell, you could try a Haskell->Scala cross compiler ;)

Comment: Note that parsing Haskell doesn't get you all the way to an abstract syntax tree. Thanks to operator precedence declarations, you have to finish "parenthesizing" expressions after you've looked up where each operator comes from (GHC calls this "renaming").

Comment: Check out [these notes](https://www.aosabook.org/en/ghc.html) explaining how ghc compiles down to a typed lambda calculus which might be a comparatively straight forward thing to express in java. But maybe not what you intended.

Answer (score 7):

> I need to know Haskell's formal grammar structure

[Haskell's grammar](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html) is [context sensitive](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-210002.7) due to [significant indentation](http://trevorjim.com/haskell-is-not-context-free/). In both the lexical and the context-free syntax there are some ambiguities that are to be resolved by the [longest match](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch) ("maximal munch") rule.

Differences between the [syntax specification](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-17500010) and implementations do exist, supposedly none of them precisely implements the spec. Also there are a whole lot of [language extensions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-1.14.0/docs/Language-Haskell-Extension.html).

There's a [ready-made scanner definition](http://eclipsefp.sourceforge.net/repo/net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.core.jparser/antlr-src/haskell-lexer.g) out there to scan Haskell with an older version of [Antlr](https://www.antlr.org/), but still [no parsing grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/issues/210). Guess you'd have to grab the parsers from aforementioned projects (Frege, Eta) or the [ghc](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts) itself.

Looking at the [source tree](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/blob/master/compiler/parser/Parser.y) and the descriptions of [ghc-lib-parser package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-lib-parser), we learn thanks to [this post](https://www.quora.com/What-kind-of-grammar-does-Haskell-have) that GHC’s parser was produced by the [happy parser generator](https://www.haskell.org/happy/), generating a [LALR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR_parser)(1) parser. This means that Haskell’s grammar is unambiguous , not requiring happy’s [GLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLR_parser)-generating abilities.

> make a parsing library that reads Haskell code ... then translates it into Java

You want to create a Haskell-Java cross compiler. Just looking at the discrepancy of the type systems I'd say, that this is pretty far fetched. One can squeeze Haskell into JVM bytecode, but I can't imagine, that any kind of generated Java might be very useful. On the other hand Haskell compiles [internally](https://www.aosabook.org/en/ghc.html) to something called "core language", a typed lambda calculus basically. That might be a more straight forward starting point.

If you're interested, there's a [Haskell-Javascript](https://haste-lang.org/) cross compiler (based on ghc), and there's a [javascript-java](http://www.jsweet.org/) cross compiler. Problem solved! Or isn't it?

Comment: I'm aware there are already premade solutions, but I want to build Jaskell from scratch, not using any external libraries. The whole reason I decided to set out on this (admittedly foolhardy) venture is as a programming challenge to myself so I can become a better programmer.

Comment: It is my hope that in doing this, I will be able to learn more about imperative and declaritve languages, in the hopes that I might one day be able to make my own programming language from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading Haskell programs directly, you may try to read the Core or STG intermediate programs that GHC can output for the Haskell programs.

Comment: That's pretty hopeless if there are any newtypes anywhere. The coercion language in GHC Core is not for the faint of heart.